Updated Highcharts to latest and now getting Uncaught TypeError: HighchartsMore is not a function
I have a bubble chart was working fine before i updated highcharts now i get the error - Uncaught TypeError: HighchartsMore is not a function it relates to "HighchartsMore(Highcharts);"
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
HighchartsMore(Highcharts);

Im guessing they have moved it? but I cant find any documentation to say what / how i should change my code?

In version 12, the way modules are imported has been changed. It is no longer necessary to initialize them after importing. They initialize themselves, the only thing you need to do is change the syntax a bit.
// Imports for Highcharts v12
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import "highcharts/highcharts-more";

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/highcharts-react-demo-forked-6d2t7s?file=%2Findex.html&workspaceId=ws_SQD7xuD6UZfZrJ83WwT92Y
Take a look at the Upgrade Notes in the Changelog:
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/#highcharts-v12.0.0
